Indent headings in "markdown" cells in Jupyter Notebook after numbering
I am trying to number my headings in Jupyter Notebook. However, this looks quite ugly, as the size of the spaces is of course dependent on the font size.
I am looking for a way to make the text of each of my headings start at the same position, i.e. with the same distance to the left side of the cell.
Here is a code example:
## 1. &ensp; heading1
### 1.1 &ensp; subheading1
### 1.2 &ensp; subheading2
#### 1.2.1 &nbsp; subsubheading1
## 2. &ensp; heading2
### 2.1 &ensp; subheading1

And what the output looks like:
Jupyter Notebook output
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you very much!
Dennis

I see in your title that you have quotes here around markdown which makes me think you know that markdown cells in Jupyter can have more than just markdown in them. Did you try exploring HTML and LaTeX to address what you want? Be aware though this is fragile as the associated auto-generated Table of Contents is made to handle markdown. So those using modern tech to explore your notebook as a .ipynb file directly will be frustrated at typical conveniences not working. However, maybe that is not an issue. Hard to tell since you don't provide context for what you actually want to achieve.

Yes, you're right, I'm well aware that I can also use HTML and Latex in the Markdown cells. However, Latex seems to be very limited and I didn't find a satisfactory solution with HTML at first. However, after some trial and error and googling, I have now found a solution. Unfortunately it is not 100% perfect but should be sufficient for my purposes. I'll post it right away as an answer to my question. Thanks for your help.

After a lot of trial and error and googling, I have now come up with a solution myself:
## <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">1.</span> heading1
### <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">2.1.</span> subheading1
### <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">1.2</span> subheading2
#### <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">1.2.1</span> subsubheading1
## <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">2.</span> heading2
### <span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;">2.1</span> subheading1

